# Unable to write over firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to link firebase realtime time database over my android application using following code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference root = database.getReference("users");

 User user = new User("Hey","hey@hey.ca","987654321");
 root.setValue(user);
```

coding is not pushing anything over the database: for debugging I tried to print the values for root and database that worked fine, returned proper address. Where as when I implemented root.setValue(user).isSuccessful() it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

```
 root.child("node-name").setValue()
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, please provide some explanation in the answer as to why this line of code solves the problem posed by OP in the question.

Comment: Tried .setValue() it not working. But if your calling .push( ) after .setValue( ) then its working